# Android basic,, error for no reason ..

Tags: java, android

I got error when running it in the android emulator.. immediately after

i add either :

tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);  // or //

rb = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1); // for some reasons (with no other code) //

need help, i want to make the TextView change as the RatingBar change

xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:text=" " 
    android:textSize="50dp"/>

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="0" />
```

java

```
package com.examplef.rating;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv;
RatingBar rb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    rb = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);

    rb.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                boolean fromUser) {
            tv.setText(rb.getNumStars());

        }

    });
}

}
```

one of the logcat says:

```
: E/AndroidRuntime(2014): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity          
ComponentInfo{com.examplef.rating/com.examplef.rating.MainActivity}:
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RatingBar cannot be cast
toandroid.widget.TextView
```

Comment: Could you tell us what error you're getting?

Comment: Please post your logCat

Comment: Paste your LogCat Errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RatingBar cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

You have initialized your views properly. So clean and build your project once and run the app.

`rb.getNumStars()` returns an `int`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#getNumStars()

```
public int getNumStars ()

Added in API level 1
Returns the number of stars shown.

Returns
The number of stars shown.
```

So change to

```
  tv.setText(String.valueOf(rb.getNumStars()));
```

`setText` looks for a resource with the `id` which is an int value. If not found you get `ResourceNotFOundException`.

You can see the below

```
public final void setText (int resid) // what you have

public final void setText (CharSequence text) // what you need
```

Comment: @BrianRoach its declared as instance variables. If its declared inside onCreate yes i agree it needs to be final.

Comment: Yeah - I finally just caught that when I looked at it again.